# How to hide C# warning using project(.csproj) file

Tags: c#, c++

One of the C# project uses multiple C++ DLLs. I want to hide below warning in the same project.

`ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor`

I know [it can be use C# code to do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(VS.80).aspx) using code file. But in my case I want to use the project file to do this.

In C++ project file, It can be done by

```
<Link>
    <AdditionalOptions> /ignore:xxxx %(AdditionalOptions)</AdditionalOptions>
</Link>
```

Is there anyway to do this using C# project file?

Comment: I still have this issue using .NET Core 3.0  have not been able to disable the AL1073, very annoying.  anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 38):

**In the .csproj file**
Add the tag `<NoWarn>1073</NoWarn>` to the desired build configuration in a `<PropertyGroup>` tag. Suppress multiple warnings by inserting a `;`.

**In Visual Studio**
Right click the project -> property -> build tab
[image]

You can explicitly specify the warning you would like to hide or lower the warning level to do that.

Please see the two posts below for reference:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: This does NOT work for ALink warnings.  It only works for _Compiler_ (CSC) warnings.

Comment: No. It works for other warnings as well, but you must specify the full warning code. For example: <NoWarn>CA1416</NoWarn> or <NoWarn>AL1073</NoWarn>. A couple of seconds after saving csproj the green line will disappear. No need to build the whole project. However, suppress only those warnings that you are sure can be ignored. For example: you only target Windows machines, so CA1416 is meaningless.